# FIND_IN_SET() how to implement in mysql and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I Have two table in Database
here i put my two table and i want record like
**Ex> Suppose if user 1 is login and user category_id is 1,2,3  then i want record from 2nd table like Home,Marketing,Customer**
so how to fire query FIND_IN_SET() in mysql and Codeigniter

1st user_registration:
[image]

2nd category:
[image]

Comment: why do you need to use FIND_IN_SET. Simply use IN keyword

Comment: ok then how to use IN keyword, Can you give me 1 example?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593699/2469308
If it works for you, please select as accepted answer. If more requirements, let me know.

Comment: did not excute
Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause

Comment: If you normalize your tables, you won't have this problem.

Comment: @JaydevVara what are the table names. You will have to change the table names and field names in my query, as per your actual db structure

Comment: oh sorry got it,but i did not get proper output

Comment: what are you getting ? can you share the output

Comment: Options
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_name)  
Home
Only 1 Name Display

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category_name)  
Home

Comment: @JaydevVara check edited answer at 
check stackoverflow.com/a/51593699/2469308

If it works. pls upvote and mark as accepted answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177025/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-jaydev-vara).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT u.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.category_name) AS category_names, u.category_id, c.category_id
FROM user u
INNER JOIN category c ON c.category_id > 0 
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id 
GROUP BY u.user_id 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(c.category_id, u.category_id) > 0
```

Comment: This won't work because the user is storing a set of data in a column.

Comment: @bassxzero please give me solution

Comment: @JaydevVara I did, normalize your tables. I think this might help you with this specific problem. http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=hobbies.php

Comment: @JaydevVara I have updated the code. please check the edited answer. Hope it works now. Change table names as per yours

Comment: Also, as @bassxzero is suggesting, you need to normalize the tables. My suggestion is to create another table which carries user_id to category_id mapping